# Запоминание в cookies выбранных элементов

Tags: php, cookie

Как сделать запоминание выбранных элементов в куки на сутки, даже при обновлении страницы и перезапуска браузера (на php)? Прошу ответить по теме и без всяких "почитай то, сходи посмотри там." Благодарю
[image: Пример]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    foreach (checkbox() as $key => $value) {
        foreach (checkbox($key) as $k => $v) {
            if (!isset($_POST[$key][$k])) {
                cookie::remove($k);
            }
        }
    }
    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
        if (is_array($_POST[$key])) {
            foreach ($_POST[$key] as $k => $v) {
                cookie::set($_POST[$key][$k], $v);
            }
        } else {
            cookie::set($_POST[$key], $value);
        }
    }
    header("Location: ".$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
    exit();
}
class cookie {
    public function set($name, $value) {
        setcookie($name, $value, time()+86400, '/');
        return $value;
    }
    public function remove($name) {
        return setcookie($name, '', 2147483647, '/');
    }
}
function checkbox($key='') {
    $array = [
        'a' => [
            'A1'=>'Первый A',
            'A2'=>'Второй A',
            'A3'=>'Третий A'
        ],
        'b' => [
            'B1'=>'Первый B'
        ]
    ];
    if ($key) {
        return $array[$key];
    } else {
        return $array;
    }
}
?>
<form action="/" method="post">
    <?php
    foreach (checkbox() as $key => $value) {
        foreach (checkbox($key) as $k => $v) {
            if (isset($_COOKIE[$k])) {
                echo '<input type="checkbox" name="'.$key.'[]" value="'.$k.'" checked>'.$v;
            } else {
                echo '<input type="checkbox" name="'.$key.'[]" value="'.$k.'">'.$v;
            }
        }
    }
    ?>
    <button type="submit">Отправить</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Большое вам спасибо!

Comment: @Денис всегда пожалуйста

Comment: не сочтите за глупый вопрос, но в строке (приложил к комментарию) идет ошибка, я убрал isset, но безуспешно, объясните пожалуйста. public function isset($name) {
        if (isset($_COOKIE[$name]) && !empty($_COOKIE[$name])) {
            return isset($_COOKIE[$name]);
        }
    }

Comment: @Денис обновил ответ убрал `function isset()`. И добавил `isset($_COOKIE[$k])` без этого у вас появляется ошибка!

Comment: Сейчас все отлично спасибо еще раз

Comment: @Денис всегда пожалуйста

Answer (score 1):

Ну без объяснений так без объяснений:
setcookie ("TestCookie", $value,time()+86400));

Comment: Это и так понятно, что setcookie ("TestCookie", $value,time()+86400)); но ведь вопрос был как сделать запоминание выбранных элементов. Что к чему, зачем, почему.

Comment: что вам мешает в $value передать строку с выбранными элементами или для каждого выбранного элемента создать свою куку? 
У вас вопрос "Как сделать запоминание выбранных элементов в куки на сутки..." ответ setcookie ("TestCookie", $value,time()+86400)); В $value передается значение при обновлении страницы проверяете или существует кука если да то позиция будет отмечена если нет куки позиция не отмечена это если для каждой позиции своя кука. Если одна кука с строкой отмеченных позиций то строку преобразовываете в массив и проверяете если в массиве есть запись то отмечаете при выводе позиций.